# TFS 2017 Administrator Console not opening, giving error for assembly

Tags: tfs

I am getting below error while opening TFS Administrator Console.

[image: Error on opening TFS Admin Console]

The OS on server is - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Does it mean the installation has got corrupt and I need to re-install TFS Server?

Comment: Is the TFS already running fine? Or you are trying to fresh install?. If it's already running correctly, Is there is any upgrade done recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution which solved the error. It was needed to change the below Registry key value to 1 in order to solve the error.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TeamFoundationServer\16.0\InstalledComponents\ApplicationTier